# Android SyncAdapter with 2 kind of accounts

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-authenticator

I'd like to use a SyncAdapter for my application. The SyncAdapter needs an Account. In my app, there can be authenticated users and also anonymous ones. How to deal with that?

Create a fake account (anonymous) with the same Authenticator? And manage that when the user login (delete it....)? Or is there another good way to do that? Two Authenticators ? Two SyncAdapters?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course, my application needs to retrieve some data from the server

Comment: so you can keep look for not allowing fake account and share the data only with the Authenticator

Comment: An account is mandatory to use a SyncAdapter. So if my user is not connected, I need to have a fake account...

Comment: why you dot say your user to connect instead of using fake??

Comment: Because the service can be used as anonymous... Sorry Sree but you don't help me.

Comment: yes @Jerome i can't help you sorry

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've created an Anonymous account, and if the user authenticates, i remove it.